# _InactiveRpcError while using workflow

Tags: python, grpc, clarifai

Hi I tried to copy the clarifai doc to create a workflow

Below is my error code

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3e79233b3dd8> in <module>
     11       resources_pb2.Input(data=resources_pb2.Data(image=resources_pb2.Image(url='YOUR_IMAGE_URL')))
     12     ])
---> 13 response = stub.PostModelOutputs(request, metadata=metadata)
     14 
     15 if response.status.code != status_code_pb2.SUCCESS:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in __call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    824                     raise StopIteration()
    825                 elif self._state.code is not None:
--> 826                     raise self
    827 
    828 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    727     def result(self, timeout=None):
    728         """Returns the result of the computation or raises its exception.
--> 729 
    730         See grpc.Future.result for the full API contract.
    731         """

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1618805454.368000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":4134,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1618805454.368000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

To create the error, API key is an example key

```
from clarifai_grpc.channel.clarifai_channel import ClarifaiChannel
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api import service_pb2_grpc

stub = service_pb2_grpc.V2Stub(ClarifaiChannel.get_grpc_channel())

    from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api import service_pb2, resources_pb2
from clarifai_grpc.grpc.api.status import status_code_pb2

# This is how you authenticate.
metadata = (('authorization', 'Key b66dddddddddddddddddddddddddd'),)

request = service_pb2.PostModelOutputsRequest(
    # This is the model ID of a publicly available General model. You may use any other public or custom model ID.
    model_id='aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c',
    inputs=[
      resources_pb2.Input(data=resources_pb2.Data(image=resources_pb2.Image(url='YOUR_IMAGE_URL')))
    ])
response = stub.PostModelOutputs(request, metadata=metadata)

if response.status.code != status_code_pb2.SUCCESS:
    raise Exception("Request failed, status code: " + str(response.status.code))

for concept in response.outputs[0].data.concepts:
    print('%12s: %.2f' % (concept.name, concept.value))
```

I resort to grpc to solve the issue but cannot find the answer
https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/
Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Make sure you're populating the url when you're creating the PostModelOutputsRequest object - currently it just says 'YOUR_IMAGE_URL` instead of an actual URL (maybe you've sanitized it for the post).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your code again and call the same endpoint again after couple minutes, hours? The inactive RPC error usually means that the service is temporarily not available.